# Pandas dataset: get time spent

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm stuck at wrapping my head around a puzzle I'm trying to solve in pandas. Normally I use Excel to fix this in a very manual way, but I wanted to find a pandas way.

What I have is a table containing start and stop times from workers (small excerpt):

| Name | action | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | in | day1 | 08:00 |
| Bert | in | day1 | 08:09 |
| Chrissy | in | day1 | 09:00 |
| Bert | out | day1 | 11:30 |
| Adam | out | day1 | 12:00 |
| Bert | in | day1 | 12:00 |
| Chrissy | out | day1 | 18:00 |
| Earl | in | day1 | 18:00 |
| Earl | out | day1 | 23:59 |
| Earl | in | day2 | 09:00 |
| Bert | in | day2 | 09:01 |
| Chrissy | in | day2 | 10:00 |
| Bert | out | day2 | 10:11 |
| Earl | out | day2 | 10:12 |
| Bert | in | day2 | 10:15 |
| Chrissy | out | day2 | 19:00 |

I'm trying to find how much time they each spent per day... I'm fixing this with iterations in dual for-loops but I'm just missing something built-in in pandas because I've never had to go through such lengths with pandas...

Not looking for full solutions, pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line:

```
# we work with timedelta type
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']+':00')

# we want to label the `in` and `out` in pairs
df['no_action'] = df.sort_values('time').groupby(['Name','date','action']).cumcount()

# pivot table so `in`, `out` pairs are on the same row
actions = df.pivot(index=['Name','date', 'no_action'], columns='action', values='time')

# differences between `in` and `out`
actions['diff'] = actions['out'] - actions['in']

# finally sum over `Name` and `date` then pivot
actions['diff'].sum(level=['Name','date']).unstack('date')
```

Output:

```
date               day1            day2 
Name                                    
Adam     0 days 04:00:00             NaT
Bert     0 days 03:21:00 0 days 01:10:00
Chrissy  0 days 09:00:00 0 days 09:00:00
Earl     0 days 05:59:00 0 days 01:12:00
```

**Note**: this doesn't count the `in` and `out` pairs that span over midnight.

Answer (score 0):

If `time` column is not a time series, first you need to convert it to timestamp like below:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M')

# Now you just use groupby on Name and date column
person_time_spent = df.groupby(['Name', 'date'])['time'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using a pivot table.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])  # defaults to today
table = df.pivot_table(
    columns='action', values='time', index=['Name', 'date'], aggfunc='first'
)

>>> table
action                        in                 out
Name    date                                        
Adam    day1 2021-02-05 08:00:00 2021-02-05 12:00:00
Bert    day1 2021-02-05 08:09:00 2021-02-05 11:30:00
        day2 2021-02-05 09:01:00 2021-02-05 10:11:00
Chrissy day1 2021-02-05 09:00:00 2021-02-05 18:00:00
        day2 2021-02-05 10:00:00 2021-02-05 19:00:00
Earl    day1 2021-02-05 18:00:00 2021-02-05 23:59:00
        day2 2021-02-05 09:00:00 2021-02-05 10:12:00

>>> table['out'] - table['in']
Name     date
Adam     day1   0 days 04:00:00
Bert     day1   0 days 03:21:00
         day2   0 days 01:10:00
Chrissy  day1   0 days 09:00:00
         day2   0 days 09:00:00
Earl     day1   0 days 05:59:00
         day2   0 days 01:12:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```